# Ошибка Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

При выполнении запроса выводит вот такую ошибку

```
balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1979, in get_asset_balance
    res = self.get_account(**params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1954, in get_account
    return self._get('account', True, data=params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 371, in _get
    return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 312, in _request
    kwargs = self._get_request_kwargs(method, signed, force_params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 270, in _get_request_kwargs
    kwargs['data']['signature'] = self._generate_signature(kwargs['data'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 223, in _generate_signature
    m = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема ???

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager
from binance.enums import *
import os
import time
import math


api_key = os.environ.get('my_api_key')
api_secret = os.environ.get('my_api_secret')
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)


balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
print(balance)
```

Comment: my_api_key и my_api_secret в переменных окружения прописаны?

Comment: да, они есть.....

Comment: добавил ключи, можете попробовать

Comment: Если прописать просто как строки без os.environ.get  (например, `api_key = 'EP ....'`), будет работать? Сами ключи в вопрос не нужно вставлять.

Comment: Нет, не будет работать. Пишет: Объект NoneType не имеет атрибута encode

Comment: Если в коде в том виде как он в вопросе сделать print(api_key) и print(api_secret), выведет эти ключи? Если выведет ключи, а не None, значит у вас все настроено нормально, и нужно пробовать писать issue на github проекта: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues

Comment: действительно, проблема с ключами, выводит None

Comment: Значит они у вас не прописаны в переменные окружения системы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'` говорит, что в какой-то переменной, имеющей значение `None` был вызван атрибут `encode`, под это подходит `self.API_SECRET` и `query_string` в строке:

```
m = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
```

Но, маловероятно, что библиотека не составила строку в `query_string`, поэтому причина в `self.API_SECRET`

[Согласно примеру API_SECRET задается в конструкторе](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/tree/a6f3048527f0f2fd9bc6591ac1fdd926b2a29f3e#quick-start):

```
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
```

У вас эти значения берутся из переменных окружения, причем через метод `get`, который вернет `None`, если указанной переменной не будет:

```
api_key = os.environ.get('my_api_key')
api_secret = os.environ.get('my_api_secret')
```

#### Решением будут следующие варианты:

1. Прописать в систему эти переменные окружения:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Запускать, например, через bat/cmd, указав в нем переменные окружения:

   ```
   set my_api_key="11111111111"
   set my_api_secret="22222222222"

   python main.py

   pause
   ```